# Android, Closing the application by using: android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Tags: android, android-activity, exit

In my project i need to close app anyway (I know its not suggested by Android but my customer needs it).

Mostly when we close app by normal way (pressing home button), when you press and hold home button and after that pressing Task Manager you will see list of active apps in back-end. I need to remove app in such a way that it doesn't show it.

After my research i found that the way is using kill process like this.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

I tested this command in a test project and it was working fine. However, I don't know why in this project it acts as a simple `this.finish();`. I mean when I click on exit menu it should close the whole of application but it just close the activity.

I have put this code in a general (activity) class that all other activities inherit from it.

please tell me what/where is the problem? Thanks

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE, "Exit");

    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case Menu.FIRST:
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is,
>   when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute
>   determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent
>   apps. "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; "false" if
>   it should be included. The default value is "false".

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude

Comment: Thanks dear Triad, but I think its not for my case. I put it in main activity in manifest file but it doesn't work. Still when i close the app with above code, it back to last activity.

Comment: Ah okay, I thought you were asking how to remove the application from the recent apps (holding HOME button) list.  Are you trying to make every activity be destroyed in your app?

Comment: Actually my concern is, "do't let user to see application as active in Task Manager". I knew the above command that is not working in this app.

Comment: Did you try to add this to every `<activity>` in the manifest?  You can also try this in code via `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS`.

Comment: Thanks friend for all. I added MSBootUp.this.finish(); to my splash screen page after calling new intent and now it works fine. Thanks again.